# Garbled router web administration page

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, wrt54g

Sometimes, when I access my router's (Linksys WRT54G) web administration page, it comes out garbled; i.e. missing text, icons, links, form controls, etc.

Gets fixed after powering the router off then on again.

Anyone know what's causing this? Any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache and cookie. Most of the time it is caused by your browser so trying another browser would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Will try them out next time the garbling happens again.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint, not full answer. Try using different web browser. Firmware upgrade may be a good point to start as well.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to try using IE. Will do next time. Firmware's upgraded to the latest version already, so it isn't the cause of the problem.